# Accessing tsconfig.json relative to the linted file

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have a monorepo which currently has a `.eslintrc.cjs` in every package with the following:

### package ESLint config

```js
const path = require('path')
const ts = require('typescript')
const OFF = 0
const WARN = 1
const ERROR = 2

const tsConfigPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json')

const pathAliases = Object.keys(
  ts.readConfigFile(tsConfigPath, ts.sys.readFile)?.config?.compilerOptions?.paths ?? [],
)
  ?.map((key) => key.replace(/[/*@]/g, ''))
  ?.sort()
  ?.join('|')

/**
 * @type {import('eslint').Linter.Config}
 * @see https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring
 **/
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'simple-import-sort/imports': [
      ERROR,
      {
        groups: [
          ['^@?\\w'],
          pathAliases.length ? [`^@?(${pathAliases})(/.*|$)`] : [],
          ['^\\u0000'],
          ['^\\.\\.(?!/?$)', '^\\.\\./?$'],
          ['^\\./(?=.*/)(?!/?$)', '^\\.(?!/?$)', '^\\./?$'],
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

### Root ESLint config

```js
const OFF = 0
const WARN = 1
const ERROR = 2

/**
 * @type {import('eslint').Linter.Config}
 * @see https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring
 **/
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:jest-formatting/recommended',
    'plugin:sonarjs/recommended',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'prettier',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: [
      './tsconfig.browser.base.json',
      './tsconfig.browser.base.json',
      './packages/service/*/tsconfig.json',
      './packages/utility/*/tsconfig.json',
      './packages/middleware/*/tsconfig.json',
    ],
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    ecmaFeatures: {
      impliedStrict: true,
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  rules: {},
}
```

This loads the `pathAliases` from the TSConfig into the `simple-import-sort` ESLint rule. I'm wondering how I can refactor this to be in the root eslint config (i.e. for each file that's being linted, it accesses the relative tsconfig `paths` property)?

Answer (score 0):

ESLint configs are given no information about the current file being linted and there is no way to get this information into the config file.

This is because ESLint can be invoked in many ways you're probably used to using it via the built-in CLI or via an IDE extension - however they also provide an API that anybody can consume to invoke ESLint on some text - with or without a filename.